# Can't access localhost on my browsers

Tags: php, webserver, localhost, mamp

I've just installed [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/) for the first time onto my mac and I'm trying to view some PHP files I've loaded into the `htdocs` section of mamp. When I type `localhost` into my browsers, it says it can't connect to the server.

What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Start the MAMP application. If it's installed correctly it will automatically launch your default browser with `http://localhost:8888/MAMP/` MAMP runs under port 8888 by default.

To view files in htdocs simply go to `http://localhost:8888/FILENAME.php` . Be sure to add the folder(s) (directory(ies) as needed. e.g. `http://localhost:8888/site1/FILENAME.php`